# Why does (BDate) is shown as syntax error

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0vb9.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RM0v8.png)
I tried everything I can It doesn't work pls help

```
print ("Enter today's date:")
DateToday = input()
print ("Enter your birthday {yyyy/mm/d)"
BDate = input()
Age = DateToday - BDate
print Age.year
```

Comment: You missed a bracket in 2nd print statement and missed 2 brackets(open and close) in last print

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow!! It would be great if you could [read these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking a new question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want just the year for age?
in which case you would do:

```
datetoday = int(input("Enter the current year: "))
bdate = int(input("Enter your birth year: "))
age = datetoday - bdate
print ("Your age is: " + str(age))
```

You forgot to add a few brackets and are asking for unnecessary data. This will give how many years old a person is.